# Is it possible to use a Card component also for edit

Tags: usability, user-expectation, design-patterns, guidelines, cards

On our UI, we are presenting the user his saved credit cards as a list of Card components, each saved card represented as a card.
The user can save up to 5 cards which will be presented in two rows, as shown in mock:
[image]

I now want to add the option to edit a credit card which includes the following options:

1. change expiry date
2. delete card
3. set as Active

On the card, there would be an "edit" option which will flip the card from view mode to edit mode. 
In this case, I'm facing a conflict. On one hand, I know that cards are mainly used for **view** mode and maybe some very few small actions. 
On the other hand, it's kind of weird to me that the card now also becomes a form. I'm not sure the user expect it to behave in this way. moreover, the form looks too compressed since we kept the size the same as in View mode.

I didn't find any information regarding Card component as an edit mode.

I guess my question is if this behavior doesn't validate the Card definition and whether or not the user expects to this kind of behavior. 
Any other suggestions?

This is how it looks now: 
[image]

Comment: Are there more cards? Or is this the only card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no. [Cards](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#) are used to display elements with different content. When you want to edit the card content it is more convenient to do so in an appropriate layout.

**There is no need to relate the Input view with the Output view** in this case.

I believe that what you have is a [Grid with tiles](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html#) (used for items with the same content) rather than cards.

In your case I suggest using a [Full screen dialog](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior)  (or a normal dialog) for the editing view:

[image]

You can check Google Keep app for reference, where the view mode uses cards but to edit a card you are taken to an editor.

Comment: Google Keep is a good idea. I think it all comes down to the animation that keeps the user in the flow rather to just open a modal in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why not.
These (material) design guidelines are what they are, guidelines, not rules. The only reason to follow guidelines is because they often follow user convention (that what the user is used to and expects).

> I know that cards are mainly used for view mode

You say it yourself, **mainly**.

In case of Google's Material Design, it's not even excluded a card can contain a form.

> Cards display content composed of different elements whose size or supported actions vary.

Input fields and switches are content too.

In your case I would say it's great to keep in on the back of the card, because it keeps the user in context. It's clear which card is being edited. Is it what the user expects? Probably not, because I haven't seen this kind of thing in the wild so I'm expecting a lot of other users haven't therefor they can't expect it. But the animation visually communicates in a clear matter what is happening. I'm willing to bet not one user will be confused, about what happens. They might even be delighted, because of the animation and the fact that they're not pogosticking between a view with the cards and a view with just the editing options.

Comment: Nice answer :) I agree that there is no need to be constraint because of a guideline. However, in this case I believe the best solution is to make the edit mode as comfortable as possible to fit the setting controllers. Using the same card (as can be seen in the image of the OP) is more a constraint than a benefit, so the card would need to be modified and made "taller" and the next question is *why not edit it out of those boundaries?*

Comment: I also like your answer. I think you are right but as @alvaro said, I think the size of the card is a huge constraint that maybe in this case only limits us. As I comment above, I think it all comes down to the animation that will have to keep the user in context

Comment: If the fit would be too tight, resulting in an uglier interface and scaling it up just a little (mimicking as if the card comes forward towards the screen) isn't an option. Than a modal or entire other view would be the way to go yes, I agree.