# Any Alternative to Slide in Panels that does not compromise UX?

Tags: usability, gui-design, sliders, panel

We are in the process of developing an Enterprise level Web Application where certain screens have cards housing some information on them and are clickable. Upon click instead of a Modal we have currently incorporated a slide in from left pane in which further information and edit functions are provided for the user to play with.

We were thinking of a different way to showcase and provide the same information rather than the current  slide in panels style because it has been long used by us and feels old and out of the era.

Just wanted to know if there are any healthy alternatives which don't compromise on the UX and the Look [UI].

Thanks & Regards
Mel

Comment: Have you considered that there may be user backlash for changing this interaction? What studies have you made to justify the opinion that it is 'out of the era'? Have your users expressed frustration or dislike with this interaction. If not don't fix what aint broke!

Comment: Hi @RobbyReindeer , Thanks for the feedback. Just want to clarify the fact that the chance of user backlash is 0 as this project is under production currently and not pushed to public. 

Just wanted to know if there are any good alternatives to the Slide in panel because internally the component was not received well and is being proposed to a change.

My apologies for the vague description if the post was not friendly to understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you should get feedback from your users as RobbyReindeer has indicated. With that user feedback, you can design tests to incrementally redesign your web app, and see the effects of the change according to the context of your users and the application being used.

To explicitly address your question, see [Paul van den Dool's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/94497/paul-van-den-dool) answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/104489/57851

Answer (score -1):

[Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior) mentions two ways of providing more content for Cards: Either you provide a collapsible on the card that expands on click or you open a modal.